# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" in WildFly 10

Tags: java, spring, jboss, cors, wildfly

I have developed an application using Spring and Angular. I have deployed my Java Spring application on WildFly 10 and I want to send a request from my Angular front-end to my backend, but I keep getting an error in the browser console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/event/allEvents. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I have added the @CrossOrigin annotation to my java code:

```
@RestController 
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RequestMapping(path="/event")
public class EventController {

@Autowired
private EventService eventService;


@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RequestMapping(path="/addEvent",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Long addNewEvent(@RequestBody Event event){
    System.out.println("user"+event);
    return eventService.createUser(event);

}

@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RequestMapping(path="/allEvents",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Event> getAllUsers(){
    return eventService.getAllUsers();
}
```

}

I also added the relevant headers to my Standalone.xml:

```
 <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="http://localhost:4200"/>
 <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
 <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with"/>
 <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
 <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>
```

and

```
 <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
 <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
 <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
 <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/>
 <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>
```

but I am still getting the same error. I really appreciate if anybody can help me with this issue.

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 404.”*… The problem seems to just be that there’s nothing at `http://localhost:8080/event/allEvents`—the request to `http://localhost:8080/event/allEvents` returns a 404 response. Have you tried pasting `http://localhost:8080/event/allEvents` into your URL address bar and seeing what happens when you try to load it?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thank you! Yeah, so I checked and apparently, I forgot to put the .war file name in my URL. So the war file name is demo.war and all my URLs are now changed to `http://localhost:8080/demo/event/allEvents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with CORS has been fixed with the headers and the reason I was getting the 404 error was that I forgot to put the "demo.war" file name in my URL. So my URL is now changed to:

```
http://localhost:8080/demo/event/allEvents
```

and it works correctly now.